# No me detecta index.html

Tags: rutas, hosting, index

Tengo un proyecto con la carpeta src y public.
Dentro de public se encuentra mi index.html

A la hora de subirlo a un hosting (hostinger) me tira el directorio Index of y no me lee el index, recién cuando entro en public si me lee la web

Que debería hacer para que funcione? Es un proyecto estático html css js con bootstrap

Comment: Supongo que si creas un .htaccess en esa carpeta raiz de tu web que redirija todas las peticiones a public/ se arreglaría. En contenido del mismo podrian ser estas dos líneas: `RewriteEngine on` y luego `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1`... prueba a ver si te funciona

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tengo otro problema ahora que no me estaría reconociendo los estilos y algunas rutas

Comment: Entre medio de esas dos lineas pon estas otras dos líneas: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` y `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` para ver si arregla algo (no creo que todo, pero quizas los estilos si)... esas líneas indican que si el archivo o la carpeta existen no haga esa redirección, y quizas tienes tus referencias de un modo que eso lo podria solucionar.
`

Comment: A ver, la solución normal seria que pusieras tu public/ en la raiz publica directamente (pero no como carpeta public/ como has hecho, sino sus archivos y subcarpetas tal cual), pero entonces no se como quedaria tu src/ o si lo podrias poner en una carpeta al mismo nivel que tu raiz publica, pues no se el tipo de hosting que tienes ni como es. De este modo no te haria falta jugar con el .htaccess como estamos haciendo.